# keccak256 output is different on ruby vs javascript...?

Tags: web3js, javascript, keccak, ethers.js, ruby

Ruby ethereum libraries use:
https://github.com/phusion/digest-sha3-ruby

```
require 'digest/sha3'
'0x' + Digest::SHA3.new(256).hexdigest('0x0')
=> "0x77b7d82d931e1a403db0240b08c0716665eec4664af617c457918e4a67bc1810"
```

... Yet over in javascript land (using both web3 or ethers):

```
web3.utils.keccak256('0x0')
=> '0xbc36789e7a1e281436464229828f817d6612f7b477d66591ff96a9e064bcc98a'

ethers.utils.keccak256('0x0')
=> '0xbc36789e7a1e281436464229828f817d6612f7b477d66591ff96a9e064bcc98a'
```

Why are these outputs different?

*UPDATE*

It appears the problem is when '0x' is prefixed the js libraries are treating things differently.

```
> web3.utils.sha3('255')
'0xbebb351b5cf10820d8521e899df75c3dc4c8d740dcf450f315119f5c837945c0'
```

and in ruby:

```
'0x' + Digest::SHA3.new(256).hexdigest('255')
=> "0xbebb351b5cf10820d8521e899df75c3dc4c8d740dcf450f315119f5c837945c0"
```

but then as hex:

```
> web3.utils.sha3('0xff')
'0x8b1a944cf13a9a1c08facb2c9e98623ef3254d2ddb48113885c3e8e97fec8db9'
```

and in ruby:

```
'0x' + Digest::SHA3.new(256).hexdigest('0xff')
=> "0x420daffad4b177bce28bead5f76f7bc97ef63c3aae74c496db8ce6aafe9e6513"
'0x' + Digest::SHA3.new(256).hexdigest('ff')
=> "0x979b141b8bcd3ba17815cd76811f1fca1cabaa9d51f7c00712606970f81d6e37"
```

...

And then this makes even less sense to me:

```
> web3.utils.sha3('0x0')
'0xbc36789e7a1e281436464229828f817d6612f7b477d66591ff96a9e064bcc98a'
> web3.utils.sha3('0x00')
'0xbc36789e7a1e281436464229828f817d6612f7b477d66591ff96a9e064bcc98a'
> web3.utils.sha3('0x000')
'0x54a8c0ab653c15bfb48b47fd011ba2b9617af01cb45cab344acd57c924d56798'
> web3.utils.sha3('0x0000')
'0x54a8c0ab653c15bfb48b47fd011ba2b9617af01cb45cab344acd57c924d56798'
> web3.utils.sha3('0x00000')
'0x99ff0d9125e1fc9531a11262e15aeb2c60509a078c4cc4c64cefdfb06ff68647'
> web3.utils.sha3('0x000000')
'0x99ff0d9125e1fc9531a11262e15aeb2c60509a078c4cc4c64cefdfb06ff68647'
```

0x0 or 0x00 or 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is all just 0, so why would those result in different digests?

Comment: A possible difference is that web3.js will accept an hexadecimal string and will convert to a bytes sequence before processing it. Other libraries will not make such conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the answer is the format of the string being given to ruby's SHA3 implementation:

```
'0x' + Digest::SHA3.new(256).hexdigest("\xff")
```

will give the same output as:

```
web3.utils.sha3('0xff');
```

Answer (score 0):

The SHA3 gem is no longer maintained and broken for Ruby 3. In addition, it's also ambiguous concerning the SHA3 vs. Keccak confusion. Therefore, I created a [`keccak`](https://github.com/q9f/keccak.rb) digest specifically for Ethereum.

To generate the same hash:

```
Digest::Keccak.new(256).hexdigest("\x0")
# => "bc36789e7a1e281436464229828f817d6612f7b477d66591ff96a9e064bcc98a"
```

Note that it cannot determine whether `0x0` is a string or a hex-number and your hash in the question is the hash over the string literal of `"0x0"`.